# How can I know which Debian libraries Electron needs to run?

Tags: linux, docker, electron, debian, balena

#### What I'm doing

I'm building an Electron-based kiosk app using Balena to run on a Raspberry Pi 4. Balena requires a Dockerfile to build the container that will run my app. In that Dockerfile, I must make sure I install all the libraries needed by Electron. The image I'm using is based on Debian Buster (the default image Balena uses).

#### What I know

I've found two working examples in GitHub similar to what I'm trying to do where I can see which libraries are installed:

- https://github.com/Ciantic/balena-electron-example ([list of installed libraries](https://github.com/Ciantic/balena-electron-example/blob/17a4f93b65f7ab5909044b39a4e472a64dcc4bf4/Dockerfile#L15))
- https://github.com/balena-io/balena-electronjs ([list of installed libraries](https://github.com/balena-io/balena-electronjs/blob/master/Dockerfile.template#L48-L70))

And also two files inside the Electron repo that mention required libraries:

- https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/77049545050673949b2844f17b3731196947956a/build/install-build-deps.sh#L189-L231
- https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/d5ab63b1ead93dcb4e3099fccd4670fe9258ca9c/docs/development/build-instructions-linux.md

#### What's confusing me

Each list of libraries in the above files is different from the others. I don't know which one I should follow. Also, the [build instructions for Linux](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/d5ab63b1ead93dcb4e3099fccd4670fe9258ca9c/docs/development/build-instructions-linux.md) don't have any list specific for Debian.

#### My question

How can I know for sure exactly which libraries I need to install in my Debian-based container so that Electron can run?

Answer (score 0):

In the example, it should show a Dockerfile that you can use to get the required libraries.

Comment: @gustavopch To add on to this, Docker should be managing the dependencies when building the Docker image -- you don't have to pre-install them. Looking at the first example link myself, it appears that Electron will be installed in the built image, so you should be good there. Edit and clarify, or post a new question if there are other problems after building the Docker image.